# How to get a upload button in swagger for IFormFile combined with other properties?

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a Asp.net core 3.1 web api with Swagger to upload files to server. the following code is working fine:

```
    [HttpPost("PostFile")]
    public ActionResult PostFile(IFormFile uploadedFile)
    {            
        var saveFilePath = Path.Combine("c:\\savefilepath\\", uploadedFile.FileName);
        using (var stream = new FileStream(saveFilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            uploadedFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

I get a nice upload button in swagger when I try to run this.

[image]

However, now I wanted to use a different model. that has some more properties along with the IFormFile.

```
public class FileUploadRequest
{
    public string UploaderName { get; set; }
    public string UploaderAddress { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to use this model, I dont see any upload button in Swagger that will help me to attach the file in the request.

[image]

For some reason, it shows the IFormFile as String. How can I get a upload button here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core Web API, it binds `application/json` format data by default. But what your model need is `multipart/form-data` type data. So you need `[FromForm]` attribute to specific the source.

I use `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` version **5.6.3** in ASP.NET Core 3.1:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostFile([FromForm]FileUploadRequest model)
{

}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use IFormFile again in [HttpPost] so you can see the button.

```
    public class FileUploadRequest
        {
            public string? UploaderName { get; set; }
            public string? UploaderAddress { get; set; }
            public IFormFile? File { get; set; }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult PostFile(IFormFile file, FileUploadRequest model)
        {
           
                var saveFilePath = Path.Combine("c:\\savefilepath\\", model.UploaderAddress!);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(saveFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                  file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
                return Ok();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

what to do when im getting only 1 IFormfile field for controller, its not showing a button but, when i add any field it appears

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ImportData([FromForm] IFormFile file = default!)
        => Ok(await _productService.InsertDataFromFile(file));
```

no button. but if i add int number, near this IFormFile, it appears

sorry for bad english